# Associative array key value pair or Mysql alias name is more efficient

Tags: php, mysql

Associative array key name or Mysql alias name is more efficient

I have a mysql table called student having columns id, name and age

I need to get the result like

> student_id  student_name    age

I have two options:

```
$sql = "SELECT id as student_id, name AS student_name, age FROM student";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($studentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $studentInfo[] = $studentRow;
    }
}
```

OR

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, age FROM student";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $i=0;
    while ($studentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $studentInfo[$i]['student_id'] = $studentRow['id'];
        $studentInfo[$i]['student_name'] = $studentRow['name'];
        $studentInfo[$i]['age'] = $studentRow['age'];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

> Note: Don't put solutions to alter the table column names.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first is more efficient and more appropriate. Because in second option, you need restore value from one array to another array that can take little bit more time.

So according to me, first option will be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Consider the case, for a large mysql database, alias name applying and fetching the data, What do you think?

Comment: For large database, you can also apply this.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql alias name is more efficient, because may be in future you will also have Class table with `id` field in it. You can resolve this conflict by using alias like `AS class_id`.

Comment: Thanks. Forget about the future, With the current structure what do you think about fetching data from a huge database?